# How do I stop my command queue loop using so much CPU properly?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a while loop that checks if an arraylist containing commands for the program to execute is empty. Obviously it does things if not empty, but if it is right now I just have a Thread.sleep(1000) for the else. That leaves anything that interacts with it rather sluggish. Is there any way to get the thread it runs on to block until a new command is added? (It runs in it's own thread so that seems to be the best solution to me) Or is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wait()` and `notify()` to have the threads that *add* something to the list inform the consumer thread that there is something to be read.  However, this requires proper synchronization, etc..

But a better way to solve your problem is to use a `BlockingQueue` instead.  By definition, they are synchronized classes and the dequeuing will block appropriately and wakeup when stuff is added.  The [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) is a good class to use if you want your queue to not be limited.  The [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) can be used when you want a limited number of items to be stored in the queue (or `LinkedBlockingQueue` with an integer passed to the constructor).  If a limited queue then `queue.add(...)` would block if the queue was full.

```
BlockingQueue<Message> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Messsage>();
...
// producer thread(s) add a message to the queue
queue.add(message);
...
// consumer(s) wait for a message to be added to the queue and then removes it
Message message = queue.take();
...
// you can also wait for certain amount of time, returns null on timeout
Message message = queue.poll(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: I toyed with the wait() and notify() methods but the thread seemed to get stuck, it never got the notify. My queue only contains strings, which would be the best blocking queue? Edit: oh yes, I also got illegal monitor state exception or something like that using wait(). No idea how to fix it. Sorry for the lack of formatting, I'm on my phone.

Comment: As mentioned `LinkedBlockingQueue` is fine if you want your queue to be unlimited.  `ArrayBlockingQueue` if you want it to have a certain number of items only.

Comment: Illegal monitor exception means that you are not `synchronized()` on the object you are calling `wait()` or `notify()` on.   Using a `BlockingQueue` is a lot easier than using your own signally which is challenging.

Comment: Just implemented LinkedBlockingQueue and it works perfectly with minimal changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`BlockingQueue<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for your commands.
There's a very good example of how to use it in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use an ExecutorService. This combines a queue and a pool of threads.

```
// or use a thread pool with multiple threads.
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// call as often as you like.    
executor.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        process(string);
    }
});

// when finished
executor.shutdown();
```